# Load CanvasFacebook.dll without Unity Integration (or other bridge options)

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I am working on Unity3d game that I wish to publish on Facebook.

Information about setup:

- Unity 4.6.1
- [Unity Facebook SDK v6.1.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads)
- I am using OS X to build. Testing game in Safari.

As you know, Facebook Canvas provide option to use Unity Integration. Description of this options is:

> "Yes" to use the Facebook Unity SDK

But I want to have custom canvas page that is shown before unity player is loaded. So that's why I need to stop using Unity Integration of Facebook Canvas. So currently I have a server that serves my application. Everything works fine except the unity plugin.

First problem I faced is the lack of `CanvasFacebook.dll` and `AuthToken.unityhash` files. I solved this by downloading them from [this link](http://integrated-plugin-canvas-rsrc.fbsbx.com/rsrc/unity/lib/sdk_6.1/CanvasFacebook.dll) (dll) and [this one](http://integrated-plugin-canvas-rsrc.fbsbx.com/rsrc/unity/key/sdk_6.1/AuthToken.unityhash) (unityhash). And placed them in appropriate paths (`rsrc/unity/lib/sdk_6.1/CanvasFacebook.dll` and `rsrc/unity/key/sdk_6.1/AuthToken.unityhash`) on my server. So now `FB.cs` loads this dll without problems.

But now I another problem. In `FB.cs` there is a code:

```
var fb = typeof(FBComponentFactory)
         .GetMethod("GetComponent")
         .MakeGenericMethod(facebookClass)
         .Invoke(null, new object[] { IfNotExist.AddNew }) as IFacebook;
```

This code works when I use Unity Integration in Facebook Canvas. But when I disable Unity Integration and run application inside of facebook - mentioned code executes and fails (without any errors or messages). How do I know that it fails? Well, it doesn't go further. Simple check - add `Debug.Log("Got/Added CanvasFacebook component");` right after `var fb = ... ;` and see that `Log` method is not called. BTW, I have a log handler that calls something like `Application.ExternalCall("console.log", message)`, but with some pretty stuff.

Ok, so I tried to check, why this code is not working with custom canvas. Why I think that dll is loaded and should work? Because right after

var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes, authTokenWww.text);
   ...
   var facebookClass = assembly.GetType(facebookNamespace + className);

`facebookClass` is not null and equals to `CanvasFacebook`. More over, I found that

```
var methodInfo = typeof(FBComponentFactory)
                 .GetMethod("GetComponent")
                 .MakeGenericMethod(facebookClass);
```

Also works. It's just the problem with invoking this method. When I try to

```
var fb = methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { IfNotExist.ReturnNull }) as IFacebook;
```

Call works, but `fb` is `null`. So I checked `FBComponentFactory` class using `ILSpy` on `IFacebook.dll` from sdk. And here is class definition:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
namespace Facebook
{
    public class FBComponentFactory
    {
        public const string gameObjectName = "UnityFacebookSDKPlugin";
        private static GameObject facebookGameObject;
        private static GameObject FacebookGameObject
        {
            get
            {
                if (FBComponentFactory.facebookGameObject == null)
                {
                    FBComponentFactory.facebookGameObject = new GameObject("UnityFacebookSDKPlugin");
                }
                return FBComponentFactory.facebookGameObject;
            }
        }
        public static T GetComponent<T>(IfNotExist ifNotExist = IfNotExist.AddNew) where T : MonoBehaviour
        {
            GameObject gameObject = FBComponentFactory.FacebookGameObject;
            T t = gameObject.GetComponent<T>();
            if (t == null && ifNotExist == IfNotExist.AddNew)
            {
                t = gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
            }
            return t;
        }
        public static T AddComponent<T>() where T : MonoBehaviour
        {
            return FBComponentFactory.FacebookGameObject.AddComponent<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

So now I think that the problem is with adding component. But it doesn't throw any errors (well, I couldn't catch any using `try catch`). So I tried to AddComponent from `FB.cs` explicitly (I know that this is ugly hack, but I am just trying to understand the root of problem):

```
var type = typeof(FBComponentFactory);
Debug.LogError("I got type: " + type);
var fieldInfo = type.GetField("facebookGameObject", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
Debug.LogError("I got fieldInfo: " + fieldInfo);
var go = fieldInfo.GetValue(null) as GameObject;

if (go == null) {
    Debug.LogError("go is null, so creating new one");
    fieldInfo.SetValue(null, new GameObject("UnityFacebookSDKPlugin"));
    go = fieldInfo.GetValue(null) as GameObject;
}

Debug.LogError("I got go with name: " + (go == null ? "null" : go.name));
var component = go.AddComponent(facebookClass);
Debug.LogError("got component of type: " + component.GetType());
var fb = component is IFacebook;
```

I use log errors, because they will call `console.error` and it's a bit easier to see in browser logs.

So when I build game with this changes and run inside of facebook canvas, I see next output:

```
[Error] 7.24    I got type: Facebook.FBComponentFactory
[Error] 7.24    I got fieldInfo: UnityEngine.GameObject facebookGameObject
[Error] 7.24    I got go with name: UnityFacebookSDKPlugin
```

But the code `Debug.LogError("got component of type: " + component.GetType());` is not executed. No errors, no exceptions. Executer (or how does it called) simply moves out from this method and goes on. I can play my game, but facebook plugin is not working.

And again. Previous code doesn't throw any exceptions (at least, I couldn't catch them using `try catch`).

Also, when I check `Player.log` file, I see:

```
7.24    I got type: Facebook.FBComponentFactory
7.24    I got fieldInfo: UnityEngine.GameObject facebookGameObject
7.24    I got go: UnityFacebookSDKPlugin
7.24    got component of type: Facebook.CanvasFacebook
```

So it shows that everything is fine. But actually, plugin is not loaded. When I try to use `FB.Login` I see:

```
180.49  Facebook: tried to login but we're not init'd yet.
```

**Question(s)**

Sorry for such long post. But here are my questions:

- Does anyone know what the hell is happening here?
- Is it possible that `CanvasFacebook` dll is corrupted?
- I couldn't find any information about such behaviour of `AddComponent`. Have anyone experienced something similar?

And main question:

Is it possible to use Facebook Unity SDK **and** custom canvas? I know that I can just create my own bridge between JS SDK and Unity SDK, but I don't like the idea, when I know that someone already created it and the only problem - creating `CanvasFacebook` component.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is rather old. But since version `7.0.0` of facebook plugin described flow is possible.

For more information checkout [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas).